# Remove const-ness from a variable

Tags: c++, casting, constants, const-cast

i'm trying to remove const-ness from a variable (char*), but for some reason when i try to change the value, the original value of the const variable still remains the same.

```
 const char* str1 = "david";
 char* str2 = const_cast<char *> (str1);
 str2 = "tna";
```

now the value of str2 changes but the original value of str1 remains the same, i've looked it up on Google but couldn't find a clear answer.

when using const_cast and changing the value, should the original of the const variable change as well ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of `str1` is `const char*`. It is the `char` that is `const`, not the pointer. That is, it's a pointer to `const char`. That means you can't do this:

```
str1[0] = 't';
```

That would change the value of one of the `const` `char`s.

Now, what you're doing when you do `str2 = "tna";` is changing the value of the pointer. That's fine. You're just changing `str2` to point at a different string literal. Now `str1` and `str2` are pointing to different strings.

With your non-`const` pointer `str2`, you *could* do `str2[0] = 't';` - however, you'd have undefined behaviour. You can't modify something that was originally declared `const`. In particular, string literals are stored in read only memory and attempting to modify them will bring you terrible misfortune.

If you want to take a string literal and modify it safely, initialise an *array* with it:

```
char str1[] = "david";
```

This will copy the characters from the string literal over to the `char` array. Then you can modify them to your liking.

Comment: Okay, so is there a way i can change the value of the const char* variable using casting  ?

Comment: @DavidFaiz You can modify the pointer just fine without the cast. You *can't* modify the `char` if you've set the pointer to point at a string literal, which you have. String literals are constant. See my latest edit for how to copy a string literal to an array.

Comment: yea just seen it and got it !
thank you very much for the quick reply !

so basically i cannot modify the literal string but just use the const char variable and point to a diffrent one.

Comment: Only literals are originally declared as const right?

Comment: @DavidFaiz if this has fully answered your question, you should consider marking it as the accepted answer, by clicking the check mark on the left side.

Answer (score 3):

`str2` is simply a pointer. And your code just changes the value of the pointer, the address, not the string to which it points.

What's more, what you are attempting to do leads to *undefined behaviour*, and will most likely result in runtime errors. All modern compilers will store your string `"david"` in read-only memory. Attempts to modify that memory will lead to memory protection errors.

Comment: Compilers verify at compile time if const variables are being used out of its context or use tricks(conditionally) when on runtime to avoid it. What you're saying about it writing to read only memory seems debased, maybe you tried to say the above?

Compilers should not write to ROM, to begin with, only very well tested software or data pieces user intend to record on something like a CD-ROM should be directed to be written on such since it's a very limited compared to RAM or other volatiles resources.

Comment: @marcelo The variable is not const, the data to which it points is const. And here when we talk about read only memory it is RAM, but the virtual memory system is used to mark this block of memory as being read only. Are you familiar with virtual memory and protection?

Comment: I get what you mean, I thought it was hardware read-only memory at first, but it's about literal machine instruction or some layer which simulates the read-only value.